# My UPDATE query in mysql perl is not updating. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am wanting to take data from mysql, display it, have users edit this data and then save it to the database.  I have all currently working except the saving to the database part.  I have been lead to believe that the UPDATE query in mysql is how you get this to work.  I put an UPDATE query in place and had no luck.  Has anyone here experienced this issue before?  I have read several posts here and on perl monks about this issue and can't seem to find an answer that solves my problem.  I will put some of my code below.  Thanks!

```
    my $dbh=DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:survey_one", "user", "password", { PrintError =>0, RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;


    my $edit_sql = q{UPDATE new_survey SET question = ? WHERE title= ?};

    my $sthe = $dbh->prepare($edit_sql);
    $sthe->execute($questionedit, $marathon);
    $sthe->finish();
```

I'd like to note that if I were to SET the question column to a string like 'does this work?' I would have success.  It's when I try to use user input $questionedit, which is defined as 
$questionedit = param('editquestion');   This is where users can edit the question field.

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: `prepare`+`execute`+`finish` can be replaced with `do`

Answer (score 1):

The following are the four possible outcomes:

1. Nothing happens because the code isn't executed.
2. An exception is thrown because an error occurred (and `RaiseError => 1` was used). The exception will end up being printed to STDERR unless caught.
3. `->execute` returns the string `0E0` (which is true, but numifies to zero) because no rows were updated because the `WHERE` clause didn't match any rows.
4. `->execute` returns a positive number indicating the number of rows modified.

Determine which case is applicable, and you'll know how to move forward.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I ended up spotting the problem.  I wasn't identifying the data individually so it wasn't updating.